# Correlation to distinguish between solid line and dashed line

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Want to sound out whether auto correlation is a good idea to distinguish between a solid line and a dashed line.

I am given fixed size image consisting of dashed line (the  gap of variable frequency in different images) and solid line(the length of solid line may not extend to the full image size)

At first, I started out to collect the patch window intensity of the image along its length and gotten its patch intensity ratio (total intensity of each patch / size of patch * 255) in a std::vector of floats

Thought of using **patch ratio > threshold number** as a form of detection. However this would fail encountering a solid line that does not extend fully to the entire length of image.

Somebody suggested using autocorrelation to detect presence of multiple peaks meeting threshold(hope I got it right). Now I have a few questions here

1. Is this method really feasible? Or there could be other metrics or method to distinguish between dashed and solid lines
2. Do anyone has the code to do autocorrelation with std::vectors? Or could kindly point me to an implementation. I am using OpenCV and C++

BTW, Here is my image

a dashed line
[image: A incomplete dashed line]

A solid line
[image: A solid line]

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach would be to use the observation that a dashed line has fewer pixels than a solid line. Using this information, we can use [`cv2.countNonZero()`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#countnonzero) to determine the amount of non-zero elements. Since your image is already thresholded, the image with more pixels should be the solid line while the image with less pixels should be the dashed line.

Results:

> ('dashed', 246)
>
> ('solid', 1193)

My implementation was in Python but you can easily covert it to C++ using the same idea

```
import cv2

dashed = cv2.imread('dashed.png')
dashed = cv2.cvtColor(dashed, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
solid = cv2.imread('solid.png')
solid = cv2.cvtColor(solid, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

cv2.imshow('dashed', dashed)
cv2.imshow('solid', solid)

dashed_pixels = cv2.countNonZero(dashed)
solid_pixels = cv2.countNonZero(solid)

print('dashed', dashed_pixels)
print('solid', solid_pixels)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: thanks for helping. could be an answer. there is some instances that this might not work... maybe I will use this as a feature to be included for SVM